# Extracted all information from midi file usign music21

Tags: python, python-3.x, music21

I'm trying to extract notes, chords and rests from a midi file with 10 instruments using `music21`, following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49339622/how-to-extract-individual-chords-rests-and-notes-from-a-midi-file) i'm able to get these for each instruments:

```
file = 'example.mid'
midi = converter.parse(file)  
parts = instrument.partitionByInstrument(midi) 
notes_for_instruments = []
for i in range(len(parts.parts)): 
    notes_to_parse = parts.parts[i].recurse()
    instr = parts.parts[i].getInstrument()
    instruments.append(instr.instrumentName)
    notes, quarters = [],[] 
    for element in notes_to_parse:   
        if isinstance(element, note.Note):  
        # if element is a note, extract pitch   
            notes.append(str(element.pitch))
        elif(isinstance(element, chord.Chord)):  
            # if element is a chord, append the normal form of the   
            # chord (a list of integers) to the list of notes.   
            notes.append('.'.join(str(n) for n in element.normalOrder))  
        elif isinstance(element, note.Rest):
            notes.append('Rest')

    notes_for_instruments.append(notes)
```

This the amount of note, chords and rest for each instruments

```
StringInstrument 2928
None 949
Taiko 29
Timpani 14
Trumpet 616
Flute 2938
Clarinet 2417
Violoncello 32
Oboe 1076
Horn 411
Bassoon 1749
```

as you can see they are very different, this occurs since i'm not extracting all the available information. How can homologate this result in order to synchronize chords, notes and rest of the several instruments?